# AJAX no funciona, no pinta fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Hola que tal buenas tardes compañeros tengo un problema con mi codigo ajax lo que sucede es que al mandar a llamar mi función drawnCalendar() desde c# ejecuta bien incluso entra al success de la funcion pero no logro hacer que pinte fullcalendar lo raro es que lo pinta solo una vez cuando inicia la pagina
Se que funciona el success por que eh mandado alerts y las muestra sin inconvenientes

```
 <%@ Page Title="Kardex" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Kardex.aspx.cs" Inherits="Kardex" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/alertify.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="plugins/ui/jquery-ui.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ui/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/fullcalendar/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        table select { font-size:11px !important; padding:0 !important }

        table {font-size:11.5px}                       
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server"> <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
            Empleado
          </h1>
          </section>
                <!-- Main content -->
                <section class="content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <!-- left column -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <!-- general form elements -->
                      <div class="box box-primary">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                          <h3 class="box-title">Kardex Empleados</h3>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                            </div><!-- /.pull-right -->
                        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                        <!-- form start -->
                          <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Número de Empleado</label>
                                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumEmpleado" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="5"
                                                AutoComplete="off"
                                                                AutoPostBack="true" >
                                           </asp:TextBox>
                                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(*) Campo Requerido"
                                                ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtNumEmpleado" ValidationGroup="vg_reporte">
                                           </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </div>    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <br />
                                           <asp:Button ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" Text="Buscar" 
                                                CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="vg_reporte" onclick="btnBuscar_Click" 
                                                ></asp:Button>
                                        </div>    
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnExcel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Descarga Excel
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div id="calendar">

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvKardex" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" GridLines="None" 
                                            EmptyDataText="Sin información"
                                        >
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          </div><!-- /.box-body -->

                          <div class="box-footer">

                          </div>

                      </div><!-- /.box -->
                      </div>
                      </div> 
                </section>


<script>

    //AJAX

    function drawCalendar() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: "{}",
            url: "Kardex.aspx/MyMethod",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (data) {
                //eventos = data.d;
                //alert(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                //drawCalendar(data.d);

                $('div[id*=calendar]').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        /*left : '',*/
                        center: 'title',
                        /*right: ''*/
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.start = item.start;
                        event.title = item.title;
                        return event;
                    }),
                    loading: function (bool) {
                        if (bool) $('.loading').show();
                        else $('.loading').hide();
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
                alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Mi codigo en C#

```
static IList events = new List<Event>();
 protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buscar();
    }

    public void buscar()
    {
        try
        {
             //Ejecuto Procedimiento Almacenado

                while (lector.Read() == true)
                {
                    if (lector["Concepto 1"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        events.Add(new Event
                        {
                            title = lector["Concepto 1"].ToString(),

                            start = lector["Fecha"].ToString(),
                            backgroundColor = "#f56954",
                            borderColor = "#f56954"
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            excepciones(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
[WebMethod]
    public static IList MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            //Do here server event  
            IList eventos = new List<Event>();

            eventos = events;

            return events;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: En el código de C# que colocaste no veo dónde llamas al método `drawCalendar();`  y ¿para qué tienes `//drawCalendar(data.d);`, es otra función?

Comment: Donde esta el metodo `drawnCalendar()`? No lo veo.

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo problema con mapas de google. Se mostraban al cargar la página y después si modificaba dinámicamente latitud y longitud y pintaba el mapa, se quedaba en blanco. La solución para mí fué que al cambiar los datos tuve que reinicializar el mapa con los nuevos datos. Entonces ya se dibujaba. Creo que es lo que te está  pasando por lo que explicas.

Comment: @Einer drawnCalendar esta en mi codigo .aspx el primero,

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Eso eran pruebas que esta realizando por eso esta comentado esa linea de codigo

Comment: @JuanLuis Enserio lo intentare y les comento que paso gracias.